How to remove hidden tag on row in django if specific value was choosen in column in another row
I'm using Django to create site and need to show column only if specific value was choosen on column
ie if i choose 'medium' in difficult column 'level' column show up:
forms.py
from django import forms
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Layout, Submit, Column, Row


difficult = (('1', 'low'), ('2', 'medium'), ('3', 'hard'),)
level = (('1', 'bad'), ('2', 'decent'), ('3', 'briliant'),)


class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    difficult = forms.ChoiceField(choices=difficult, label='Choose level')
    level = forms.ChoiceField(choices=level, label='Choose level')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            Row(Column('difficult', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'), css_class='form-row'),
            Row(Column('level', css_class='form-group col-md-4 mb-0'), css_class='form-row', hidden = 'true'),
            Submit('submit', 'submit', css_class="btn-success")
        )

views.py
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import ContactForm


def index(request):
    form=ContactForm()
    if request.GET:
        temp = request.GET['module']
        print(temp)
    return render(request,'info.html',{'form':form})

info.html
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body style="padding:20px;">
    <h1 class="mt-2" style="text-align:center;font-weight:bolder;color:steelblue;">Choose</h1>
    <hr class="mt-0 mb-4">
    {% crispy form form.helper %}
</body>
</html>

models.py
class ModelName(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

I know there must be js since it's tool that work on client side, but have no idea how to use that there.
There's similar question, but there some params and classes outside of provided code that i cant
In finale i want to download a xml file with choosed options after pressing submit button, but i will figure out how do to it after.

are you referring to hiding/unhiding fields or chained dropdowns?
JS would definitely be a component, but possibly so would ajax if you're talking about chained dropdowns.

i guess chained dropdowns, but not see conceptual difference there? I thought in js chained dropdown work via hiding/unhiding fields

nope. so chained dropdowns would be setting the options/values of a dependent dropdown based on the selection of the initial dropdown. To populate these would be an ajax call back to the serverside to get the new values. I would think this would work better across models  (e.g. you start with a list of countries, depending on the country selected, you display in the secondary dropdown a list of cities in that country. if you change countries, the cities list changes). This would be best done by 2 models: city and country with FK on city pointing back to country model

alternatively, if you're talking about hiding/showing fields based on a tickbox, this is a completely different scenario and would be best handled by JS to hide/show the field based on the value of that tickbox. This wouldn't necessarily change the value of the field based on prior selection, but would be more hide/show in nature only.

Yeah, i'm probably wan't to use ajax call back and show countries > cities, but what if i choose vatican as a country and i don't need it to open new dropdown, but choose vatican it self, would this still work using ajax? If yes, would look into it thank you.

vatican city is the city in the country vatican city.
However, if there's a chance the dropdown would have no 'child' dropdown, this would be a combination of chained dropdowns and a show/hide function.... it gets complex quickly.
